# How to request resend of Toll by Mail - NY

Tags: new-york-city, tolls

I traveled to New York and went through a toll bridge off of the Jersey Turnpike.  They said they would mail me the toll, but I believe it was sent to the wrong address and I can't get it.  I waited too long and now I can't enter my travel dates on the website.  They claim you can request a resend over the phone, but I cannot get there.  There is no other means of contact besides the phone number which is useless if you do not have a Toll number.  Has anyone had any success contacting them, or wading through the phone tree and found the resend toll path?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. 'mail the toll'? You _paid_ the toll, and they won't give it back, not via mail and not in person. Are you asking for a _receipt_?or what?

Comment: Where did the OP mention they paid the toll?

Comment: Are you saying that you missed the toll (or went through EZpass) and the cameras captured your license plate? The address it would be sent is that of the vehicle's registered owner. BTW, you've got 48 hours to pay (or had) before a summons/fine get issued. If you can't do it in person in Woodbridge, try the email info@turnpike.state.nj.us.